# Extend Generic Inquiry Screen

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to add a custom Action to a Generic Inquiry Result screen and carry out some logic based on the data that is retrieved by the Generic Inquiry.

If it is not possible to extend the Generic Inquiry screen directly, would it be possible to create a custom screen which shows data retrieved form the Generic Inquiry?

Comment: Hi Joseph, I have been working on a project to extend the generic inquiry screen dynamically with actions that can be scheduled. The actions are written from the browser using C# complete with a modern code editor (with IntelliSense and more). Reach out to me Gabriel at Velixo.com if you want to discuss this further - I’m looking for use cases and potentially beta testers :)

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks for your comment. Yes sure, I would be interested in your project, sounds exciting :).  In the meantime, I think I managed to find a solution for my current task. Will post it in the Answer as soon as the approach is tested and verified.